# Difference between n*m table and n tables with m column each in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table in mysql in which first column of every row contain a question and next columns contain answers. Because each row may contain different number of answers so their may be mismatch in columns in each row. So i create n different tables with required number of column. So i want to know weather it is good way to handle problem or not. 
Thank You

Comment: It isn't. How about you create two tables? One for questions, one for answers, then link them up using foreign keys?

Comment: Please read what was written. I wrote **two** tables. One for questions, one for answers. You can have question saying "What's your age?" and 3 possible answers. You store question as 1 row, and answers as 3 rows. You can have a question with no answers. Or question with 1 million answers. You add *rows* to databases. Not columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea and the standard approach for this is as follows:

Question is an entity with the minimal properties of ID (`auto increment`, `PK`, `INT`) and a question in words (`text` or `varchar`)

Answer is an entity with the properties ID and answer as a string, too.

A question can have many answers, an answer can also be the answer of different questions (= many questions can have many answers (`mtm` or `m2m` relation)) (if not, 2 tables would be enough but I would reducing redundancy this way). This is your relation. In the table of relation, use a PK over 2 columns `question_id` and `answer_id`.

You need 3 tables, `question`, `answer` and `question_has_answer`.

Helpful keywords to google for: "normalization", "entity relationship"